# Casting of int array into double array in immediate window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, immediate-window

Is it possible to cast int array into double array in immediate window? I tried to cast but somehow its not working. I would like to know that is it possible or not?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That cast is illegal. Just try to compile it and you will see that it doesn't work either.

The following code will perform this conversion:

```
var d = i.Select(x => (double)x).ToArray();
```

Unfortunately, you can't use it in the immediate window because it doesn't support lambda expressions.

A solution that doesn't require lambda expressions is the following:

```
i.Select(Convert.ToDouble).ToArray();
```

This could work because there is no lambda expression. Thanks to Chris for the idea.

Comment: Would using `Convert.ToDouble` instead of the Lambda do the trick?

Comment: @Chris: You mean as in `i.Select(Convert.ToDouble).ToArray()`? Yes, that could very well work.

Comment: That is what I was thinking, yes. I've not got stuff open to test and I wasn't sure how up to the overload resolution it is when passing methods like that.

Comment: Well that's 50 rep I missed out on. ;-) Glad it worked though. For what its worth the thought process was "Lambdas aren't allowed. You could do it if you had a method already but then you'd have to write one and it takes away the point. Wait, what if there already was a method to convert between types?"

Comment: Of course this solution creates an array with a binary appearance that is very different from the original. If you wanted the same bits (but completely different numerical/mathematical meaning), you would need an array of type `long[]` instead, and then use `longArr.Select(BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble).ToArray()`.

Answer (score 11):

One more way is to use `Array.ConvertAll`

```
Array.ConvertAll<int, double>(nums, x => x);
```

Comment: Love this suggestion!  Should be faster than the LINQ solution given above.